# Assign product to category by store

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category

**I want to assign product to category by store.**

What I did :

- I update my database to add a column 'store_id' to catalog_category_product
- When I save a product to category via the BO, I insert the store_id too

**What I want to do now:**

When I go to the product to see its categories. I want to make a distinction between category just for the store and global category.

Example of categories for product :

[image: my page]

So, someone knows where is the code to get the collection which display the checked boxes ? I didn't succeed to find it.

Comment: The values for categories are stored in the `catalog_category_product` table which only holds values for the category/product ids and one for position.  I think the best solution would be to create `websites` to replace your `Store Views`, copy all your categories, and assign them to separate websites so you can then assign the products.  It could be a lot of work and sort of an ugly solution, but doing it with the data and a custom extension would be more work, and it would be seriously changing the structure of category tables in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your proposition, but the people who handle categories don't want to create new ones. So I will find another solution.

Comment: @Kozame, did you get the solution?

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari Sorry, I don't remember and now I'm on Magento 2 :(